# После закрытия одного Bootstrap Modal не выводится другой

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

При нажатии на кнопку вызывается функция, вставляющая в пустой div код Modal'a.
В Modal'e есть кнопка удаления, при нажатии на которую второй Modal должен заменить текущий Modal.
**Первый модал:**

```
<div class='modal fade' id='user_fullinfo' role='dialog'>
 <div class='modal-dialog'>
  <div class='modal-content'>
   <div class='modal-header'>
     <h4 class='modal-title'>Просмотр заявки</h4>
   </div>
   <div class='modal-body' id='modal-body'>
     <table class='table table-bordered' id='user_fullinfo_table'></table>
   </div>
   <div class='modal-footer'>
     <button type='button' class='btn btn-danger order_delete'>Удалить заявку</button>
     <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Отменить</button>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**Второй модал:**

```
<div class='modal fade' id='delete_order_question' role='dialog'>
 <div class='modal-dialog modal-sm'>
  <div class='modal-content'>
   <div class='modal-header'>
     <h4 class='modal-title'>Удаление заявки</h4>
   </div>
   <div class='modal-body' id='modal-body'>
     <p>Удалить заявку?</p>
   </div>
   <div class='modal-footer'>
     <button type='button' class='btn btn-danger entry_delete_accept'>Удалить</button>
     <button type='button' class='btn btn-default entry_delete_cancel' data-dismiss='modal'>Отменить</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Проблема: по нажатию "Удалить заявку" в первом модале он лишь закрывается, и ничего больше не происходит. Ошибок в консоли нет.
Прошу подсказать мою ошибку. Спасибо!

**UPD: решено:** в коде кнопки "Удалить заявку" отсутствовали 
data-toggle='modal' data-target='#delete_order_question', а также элемент, к которому шла привязка от data-target должен был уже существовать на момент нажатия.

Comment: Покажите функцию

Comment: Стандартная js функция "пуша", используется в обоих случаях.
`array = [];
array.push("здесь код Modal'a");
modalHTML = [];
modalHTML.push(array.join(""));
document.getElementById('modal_message').innerHTML = modalHTML; `

Comment: @Grundy здравствуйте снова :)
Если будет время, посмотрите тему, быть может, вы знаете ответ на вопрос. Спасибо заранее!